# Fastest and most efficient way to put a numpy array to Mysql db

Tags: python, mysql, numpy

So I have a two numpy array. One of the arrays contain the object_ids for my database and all of these are ints and another contains the values I want to put to my database which are floats. Also my database is a mysql db.

what is the most efficient way to put all of this to my mysql db cause Im looking to optimize my code.

im also using MySQLdb and cursors to connect to my database.

Comment: You might want to check http://turbodbc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas` as a clean interface between the two worlds.
As an example :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

index = np.arange(10)
values = np.random.rand(10,2)
names= ['a','b']

df= pd.DataFrame(values,index,names)

In [217]: df
Out[217]: 
          a         b
0  0.259787  0.313253
1  0.449761  0.363243
2  0.916497  0.204994
3  0.168862  0.718966
4  0.248206  0.106945
5  0.709540  0.902679
6  0.413442  0.933243
7  0.568530  0.427908
8  0.926834  0.967445
9  0.175371  0.952798
```

You can then use [`df.to_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) which will tranfer you data in a SQL database.

Comment: how do I upload it afterwards if Im connected to a cursor?

Comment: Never done  that, read the doc. It seems that the way is to install SQLAlchemy to connect to various DB.